# Using ember-data only for fetching data (not for committing). How not to mark records as 'uncommitted' when changing attributes?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using ember-data for fetching data from API (only using `find` methods). The data is periodically refreshed from the server. Commit operations are handled outside of ember-data.

However, when changing an attribute the record is marked as `uncommitted` and fails to refresh in the next `find` request, since it needs to be in the `loaded.saved` state.

Is there any way to force a record to remain in the `loaded.saved` whenever an attribute is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something vaguely similar to this. Try this out. Untested code!

Override the init method on your DS.Model and add an observer to each attribute on your DS.Model. The observer delegates to a callback which forces your model state back 'loaded.saved'

```
App.YourModel = DS.Model.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super();
    this.eachAttribute(function(attributeName){
      this.addObserver(attributeName, this, this.revertToLoadedSavedState);
    }, this);
  },

  revertToLoadedSavedState: function() {
    //hackity hack
    this.get('stateManager').transitionTo('loaded.saved');
  }
}
```

If that works your models will continually be in the 'loaded.saved' state. However, the number of observers is going to increase out of control as you load entity instances.

Maybe you could just iterate through your dirty models prior to doing a refresh from the server and use the stateManager to force each dirty instance to 'loaded.saved' state.

Comment: Did this work for you? You might interested in reading this: http://blog.gaslight.co/post/53361504301/an-autosave-pattern-for-ember-and-ember-data     You could reverse the autosave pattern that they describe there to keep your model in the loaded.saved state  by observing isDirty instead of having observers for each attribute